# Improve GitHub workflow performance?

Tags: angular, github, jasmine, continuous-integration, github-actions

### Background

- I have created a GitHub workflow (in `.github/workflows` directory),
- every command put there runs fine,
- and `ng build` finishes in 5 minutes.
- The problem is that my `Jasmine` unit-tests (which specify `Chrome` as runner), take *multiple hours*, which I execute like:

  ```
  ng test
  ```
- Said unit-tests take *only 1 minute* on my local.
- In the CI workflow I do specify *Ubuntu latest*,
- But I think it runs "Headless" (without UI support, which would be pretty slow, while emulating any UI code).

### Question

Is there any way to run GitHub's Workflow and/or Action NOT "Headless"?
(and by that, somehow improve performance.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to force GitHub's "Headless" server to have head (GUI support).

Nowadays we can simply configure `Jasmine` (or rather `Karma`'s target browser), to run Headless as well.

---

Change Workflow's `run` into something like:

```
npx ng test --no-watch --no-progress --browsers=ChromeHeadlessCI
```

And ensure your `karma.conf.js` has proper settings, something like:

```js
browsers: ['Chrome', 'ChromeHeadless', 'ChromeHeadlessCI'],
customLaunchers: {
  ChromeHeadlessCI: {
    base: 'ChromeHeadless',
    flags: ['--no-sandbox']
  }
},
```

> See also: https://angular.io/guide/testing#configure-cli-for-ci-testing-in-chrome

Answer (score 1):

I am thinking it is running in watch mode in your CI as well and therefore never stopping. Try creating a new script and running this new script in your ci/pipeline.

// We are turning watch off and specifying the browser as Chrome.

```
"test": "ng test",
"test:ci": "ng test --browser Chrome --watch=false"
```

Instead of `npm run test` in your CI, it should now be `npm run test:ci`. `npm run test:ci` should work locally for you as well where the tests just run once.

If that doesn't work, try following [this](https://qarunqb.medium.com/set-up-your-next-angular-9-project-for-ci-cd-on-bitbucket-pipelines-a024f6c2a2e9). Some changes are made to the `karma.conf.js` and scripts to make it work in Bitbucket CI but I am thinking you wouldn't need this.